# How to get email parameters from database

Tags: symfony

I use SwiftMailerBundle, but I want to get email username and password from the database, not from config parameters. It is possible?

I can use SwiftMailer and setting as I want, but I would like to use SwiftMailerBundle.

Comment: yes you can get the username and password from db

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible but, you have to make sure SMTP Transport called in your controller or service. You have to do in following way:

1. following snippet put in your controller or service

```
$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.XXXX.XXX.XXX', <portno>))
        ->setUsername($username) //username from database
        ->setPassword($password) //password from database
        ->setEncryption('ssl');


        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
```

Comment: I know that, but if i do it without SwiftMailerBundle, in the profiler will not be visible email logs.

Comment: Are you using following bundle?  "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",

Comment: Yes i use symfony/swiftmailer-bundle

Comment: I'm also using same bundle. However, given solution is working for me.

Comment: Yes its working, but in development environment on profiler toolbar will not be visible email logs. In that reason I want to use wiftmailer-bundle and not the clean SwiftMailer library.

Comment: Your question is for How to get value from db or about adding data in log?

Comment: My question is how to get value from db and insert it to swiftmailer-bundle configuration